# how to solve java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header name must not be empty on JSOUP

Tags: java, android, jsoup, illegalargumentexception

I'm trying to  parse HTML from a URL using Jsoup library

but when I do the debugging i found this Exception throw

```
>  12-09 08:48:09.741 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem 

W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Header name must not be empty

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:102)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Base.header(HttpConnection.java:300)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.processResponseHeaders(HttpConnection.java:850)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.setupFromConnection(HttpConnection.java:785)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:577)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:548)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:235)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:224)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem.Activities.FindEmptyPark$GetData.doInBackground(FindEmptyPark.java:474)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem.Activities.FindEmptyPark$GetData.doInBackground(FindEmptyPark.java:459)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)

12-09 08:48:09.751 5188-5422/com.example.virusmahmoudaidi.parkbookingsystem W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

this exception throw when the compiler reach to Jsoup HTML call line :-

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).timeout(0).get();
```

My HTML page :-

```html
<html> 
 <head> 
 <META charset='UTF-8' HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='5'/>

<title>Arduino Web Server</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#FF0000">

<h1>25</h1>
<br>
<h1>40</h1>
<br>
<h1>30</h1>
<br>
<h1>15</h1>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Any hint please ...

Comment: make sure your urls[0] is not empty

Comment: @elbraulio the urls[0] is not empty 
the problem on my HTML page because when i put http://www.google.com on the urls[0] the data returned without any problem
but i have no idea how can solve

Answer (score 1):

this issue is caused by name is "empty" or null

Recently, I just started my jsoup development and found this issue.

In the Map headers

Try to remove empty name header before:

headers.remove("");
headers.remove(null);